# navigator.geolocation:: Location request timed out issue React Native

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am building a React Native app and trying to get my current geocodes using navigator.geolocation It shows me an error of Location request Time out. Basically I am building a tracking app and I need to configure the exact location latitude longitude. To start tracking there is one button and click of this tracking would be start and it should be the initial point for tracking. I am using default react native geolocation API, Link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation
Function to get my current location::

```
getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response && response.coords) {
            this.saveLogs(response.coords);
        }
    },
        (error) => {
            this.onGeolocationErrorOccurCallback(error);
        },
        GeolocationOptions
    )
}
```

It shows me an Error::

> {"TIMEOUT":3,"POSITION_UNAVAILABLE":2,"PERMISSION_DENIED":1,"message":"Location
>   request timed out", "code":3}

I have added permission for Android device, and also checking by set enableHighAccuracy value to false. But it's not working for me. And I need  to set enableHighAccuracy to true because I want exact geocodes to track someone. Please suggest why Location request timed out is occurring here??

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: 2021 June 12,

This approach works for me in Android Emulator. `"react-native": "0.64.1"` and  `Android API 30`

```
import Geolocation from "@react-native-community/geolocation";

const getGeoLocaation = () => {
  const config = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 2000,
    maximumAge: 3600000,
  };

  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    info => console.log("INFO", info),
    error => console.log("ERROR", error),
    config,
  );
};
```

Comment: You have fixed my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The code below worked for me:

```
componentDidMount(){
   if(Platform.OS === 'android'){
      this.requestLocationPermission()
   }else{
      this._getCurrentLocation()
   }
}

async requestLocationPermission() {
    try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          'title': 'Location Permission',
          'message': 'MyMapApp needs access to your location'
        }
        )

       if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
           this._getCurrentLocation()
           console.log("Location permission granted")
       } else {
           console.log("Location permission denied")
       }
    } catch (err) {
       console.warn(err)
    }
}

_getCurrentLocation = () =>{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
       (position) => {
       this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude, 
       })
    },
    (error) => {
        this.setState({ error: error.message })},
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
}
```

Permission in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Just make sure your location is enabled.

Comment: I have already tried this but its not working on Redmi note 4 | Android 7, MIUI 9 |

Comment: Is it working on any other device? @HarleenKaurArora

Comment: Only moto E-4 plus but I need a working on all devices.

Comment: It's working on ios devices, but there is an issue with the most of Android devices. And I have already set permission and called above function when permission are granted

Comment: Can you tell me how can I resolve this for Android devices

Comment: And I am using default react native geolocation API , If there is any other best API to get exact geocodes? If any please suggest me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it is not working in your case. I tested this on Samsung S4 and Nexus 6P, and it worked for me.

Comment: I have tested on Redmi Note 4, Oppo F1 and Redmi 3S but it's not working.

Comment: This is worked for me .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

> enableHighAccuracy: false

Worked for me!

```
    const getUserCurrentLocation = () => {
    let latitude, longitude

    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        info => {
            const { coords } = info

            latitude = coords.latitude
            longitude = coords.longitude

            setLat(latitude)
            setLng(longitude)

            getUserCurrentAddress(latitude, longitude)
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        {
            enableHighAccuracy: false,
            timeout: 2000,
            maximumAge: 3600000
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I add the same issue ({"TIMEOUT":3,"POSITION_UNAVAILABLE":2,"PERMISSION_DENIED":1,"message":"Location request timed out", "code":3})
After reading the following documents,
https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#java
[https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation/blob/master/example/GeolocationExample.js'](https://github.com/react-native-geolocation/react-native-geolocation/blob/master/example/GeolocationExample.js%27)

I understood that, I need to add:

- in the manifest AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  ```

And increment the timeout as follow

```
    {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 2000,
        maximumAge: 3600000
    }

   -- code snipet
   Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          const initialPosition = JSON.stringify(position);
         console.log(initialPosition)
         // this.setState({initialPosition});
        },
      error => console.log('Error', JSON.stringify(error)),
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000},
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i update `enableHighAccuracy: true` to `enableHighAccuracy: false` and it worked.

```js
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position: any) => {
        const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
        setLocation({latitude, longitude});
        mapRef.current?.animateToRegion(
          {
            latitude,
            longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.1,
            longitudeDelta: 0.1 * (width / height),
          },
          0,
        );
      },
      (error: any) => {
        Alert.alert(
          'Error',
          'Failed to get current location. Please make sure location services are enabled.',
        );
        console.log('error in current location:', error);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 3600000},
    );
```